# Replace the PE stub in an existing Win32 .exe

Tags: windows, stub, portable-executable

I have an existing Win32 .exe with a PE stub in the beginning, and I have another PE stub stored in a separate file. This separate PE stub is longer than 20 KiB, the original PE stub is at most 512 bytes. I don't have the source code, so I'm not able to recompile or relink. How do I replace the PE stub in the Win32 .exe?

Probably I need a tool for that which updates section file offsets. But that's not enough: according to diff of the outputs of `objdump -x file.exe`, these also have to updated: AddressOfEntryPoint, BaseOfCode, BaseOfData, SizeOfImage, SizeOfHeaders, offsets in the data directory, addresses in relocation fixups.

Comment: When you say stub, do you mean the DOS stub meant to work in DOS mode?  Assuming this is the case *AND* you accomplish your goal by copying all 20k of your DOS stub into the PE headers and updating all other RVAs and sizes, Windows won't load a PE file whose PE Headers (including the stub) don't fit within the first page of memory (4096 bytes).  This doesn't mean it can't be done, but it would require you make some modifications to the code and relocate a portion of it.

Comment: @byteptr: Yes, I mean the DOS stub. It's incorrect that Windows won't load a program with a 20 KiB DOS stub. I've just tried it on WIndows 10 64-bit (and also in a Windows XP and in a Windows NT 3.1 virtual machine), and they happily ran the .exe.

Comment: @byteptr: Do you know of a tool which can make all the necessary changes on the .exe for replacing the stub correctly?

Comment: To the downvoter: is there a way you can recommend for me to improve this question to make it easy to answer?

Comment: The DOS stub program *can* be larger than 4096 bytes, its just that at some point, the stub needs to jump past the headers to some reserved space within the EXE to continue. Specifically the e_lfanew DOS header member, despite being 32-bits, must be an offset so that the PE header that follows fits within the first 4096 bytes. As long as the stub works around this limitation, you're good. I've heard the Microsoft linker has some sort of STUB limit from back in the day, so the original author probably coded the stub entry-point by hand.  Can you share this file somewhere so we can have a look?

Comment: Or, if you can't share the entire file, share the first 1024 bytes?

Comment: Here you go: a PE .exe with a stub longer than 100000 bytes: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/978a1b7bf78d323460238ab8b509ad8120200722010605/e7383d

Comment: The file you posted does indeed push the PE header out to nearly 100k and does indeed run under DOS Box.  However, on XP SP3 (32-bit) I get "prog.exe not a valid Win32 application".  Windows 7 x64, same message.  Under Windows 10 x64 (1909 18363.418) I get "This app can't run on your PC".

Comment: @byteptr: Here is an updated file with a >100000 byte stub which works for me on Windows NT 3.1, Windows 95, Windows XP and Wine 5.0: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/523a1cf146622755ebcba857106b147920200722030231/122687 , and also in DOSBox (which runs the stub).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TL:DR** Use the Perl script in [pe-setstub](https://github.com/pts/pe-setstub) to replace the DOS stub in a PE .exe.

Win32 PE .exe files with large stubs (even larger than 100 000 bytes) do work on various Windows versions, but there is a requirement: the VirtualAddress of each section must not be smaller than the header size (which includes the stub, the PE header and the PE section table). Thus if a program replaces the stub with a much larger one, the program also has to increase the VirtualAddress of each section. This sounds like a very complicated operation, so it's unlikely that there is some tool ready-made for that.

FYI On Win32s, there is an additional requirement: the PE header (ending with the last byte of the last section header) must fit in 0x800 (2048) bytes.

Even with these requirements, it's possible to add a long stub, without touching the VirtualAddress of sections or the ImageBase. The PE .exe would look like this:

1. 32 bytes of DOS .exe header (including a few bytes of padding at the end), starting with `MZ`. The header field at offset 8 points to the DOS stub code (#3).
2. About 368 bytes of PE header (containing 4 section headers of 40 bytes each), starting with `PE`, and ending with the last section header.
3. The rest DOS stub code, will be loaded to memory and run by DOS. This can be as small as 32 bytes, or as large as several hundred KiB.
4. Some padding bytes to align the first section to a multiple of 0x200.
5. Section data, aligned to a multiple of 0x200 each.

I've implemented such a stub replacement and splitting as a Perl script in [pe-setstub](https://github.com/pts/pe-setstub).

It works because there is no (small) upper limit on the size of #3.

Comment: Fascinating! The latest executable you provided runs on XP, Win7x64, and Win10x64 not to mention DOSBox and *does* contain a header complete with a sequential DOS stub of about 98k.  This is baffling because I've studied some of the kernel code (along with the Windows Research Kernel) and there are header checks.  I see the giant and bogus size of your .text section, but at this point I don't understand how you are getting essentially all versions of Windows to load it, bypassing the checks.  Perhaps your conclusion is indeed the case?  Anyway, thanks for this nugget of info!

Comment: @byteptr: I've managed to find a trick to replace the DOS stub with a much larger one, and implemented it. See the edited answer for details.